# 2 Network interfaces, one routed through the other

Tags: networking, debian

I have a Debian box with `eth0` configured as 192.168.0.3, with gw as 192.168.0.1 and `eth1` is configured as 10.0.0.1 and no gateway.

My home network is on the 192.168.0.0/24 network, and I am going to have IP cameras on the 10.0.0.0/24 gateway will be 10.0.0.1. Cameras will be connected to a POE switch, which also connects to the debian box and my home router(/modem).
Image to hopefully describe it better:
[image: Network diagram]

The Debian box is going to record the cameras and is hooked up to a switch. I want to be able to access 10.0.0.2 when my computer has the IP 192.168.0.2

Currently the network is configured in `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.3
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Do I need to bridge `eth1` to `eth0` to be able to ping 10.0.0.2 from my computer on 192.168.0.2. Or do I need to add a static route?

Comment: You are describing what you want to do but not what you did. Give all the details of your interface configuration. What's the purpose of your router? Is that a switch with VLANs? What does not work? Your post probably belongs better on SuperUser as this is a home setup, not an enterprise setup so our solutions might be "over your head". Here we deal more with enterprise type equipment and setups.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Rewrote it a bit better.

Comment: You don't even need two NICs for this, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your setup correctly, adding a static route to your router as follows should do the trick.

```
10.0.0.0/24 gw 192.168.0.3
```

And you will need to ensure that ip forwarding is enabled on the debian machine

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, first you should reconfigure a little bit the network as shown here:

[image]

Then, on Debian box make sure you run these commands at every reboot(add them to /etc/rc.local)

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j MASQUERADE
```

You have to push somehow the route to your computer (192.168.0.2) either by using router's configuration interface or by issuing the following command in Windows 7 CMD

```
route -p ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 192.168.0.3
```

"-p" tells Windows to preserve this route in the routing table across reboots (persistent route)

P.S: your setup is a little ambiguous as i can't figure if your switch supports VLAN's, which is a needed feature in order to use the actual physical network configuration